# Plus.Momentsapi.write(GoogleApiClient, Moment) returns {statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}

Tags: android, google-plus

I am trying to use the GoogleApiClient to write a "create image" action using a Moment (google play-services:7.0.0).
Initialization of the api client:

```
GoogleApiClient.Builder plusClientBuilder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context, this, this);
String accountName = prefs.getString(KEY_GPLUS_ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(accountName)) {
    plusClientBuilder.setAccountName(accountName);
}
plusClientBuilder.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
        .addScope(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read"));
Plus.PlusOptions plusOptions = Plus.PlusOptions.builder().addActivityTypes(new String[]{"http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/CommentActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/CreateActivity"}).build();

plusClientBuilder.addApi(Plus.API, plusOptions);
GoogleApiClient mPlusClient = plusClientBuilder.build();
```

Then on onConnect() try to write Add moment:

```
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    ItemScope authUser = new       ItemScope.Builder().setType("http://schema.org/Person").setName(username).build();
        List<ItemScope> author = new ArrayList<>();
        author.add(authUser);
        ItemScope target = new ItemScope.Builder().setUrl("http://example.com/photo?id=photoId").build();
        String scopeUrl = "http://example.com/photo/google    
        itemType=http://schema.org/ImageObject&name="+title+"&image="+imgUrl+"&description="+desc+"&creator="+userName;
        ItemScope.Builder scopeBuilder = new ItemScope.Builder().
                setUrl(scopeUrl).
                setType("http://schema.org/ImageObject").
                setName(title).
                setImage(imgUrl).
                setDescription(desc).
                setThumbnailUrl(thumbUrl).
                setAuthor(author);
        Moment moment = new    Moment.Builder().setType("http://schemas.google.com/CreateActivity").setTarget(target).setResult(scopeBuilder.build()).build();
        Plus.MomentsApi.write(mPlusClient, moment).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status result) {
         L.i("GPlus", "write moment" + result);
    }
});


     }
```

I get **{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}** on ResultCallback.
I've  enable the Google+ API in Google Developers Console, create an OAuth 2.0 Client ID, .apk file is signed via public certificate. OAuth passes successfully.

Am I doing something wrong? Does this moment type requires some other properties?